# Href having Javascript function does not show "Save Target as" on Right click

Tags: javascript, function

below is the link on my jsp page :

```
<td  height="37" align="right">
    <a  href="javascript:getPolicyPaper('/cpi/producer/CSPDocumentGateway?jadeAction=MCS02&<%= MCSUIKeys.ASP_MCS_DOCUMENT_SELECTED %>=<%= i %>&m=<%=aView.getCalMonth()%>&y=<%=aView.getCalYear()%>&p=<%=aView.getProducerNumber()%>', 'pdf', '640','550')">DOC</a>
</td>
```

Javascript function :

```
function getPolicyPaper(policyPaperUrl,policyType,windowWidth,windowHeight) {
//Calculate center of screen
var winWidth = windowWidth;
var winHeight = windowHeight;
var policyElement = policyType;
var xPos = (screen.availWidth-winWidth)/2;
var yPos = (screen.availHeight-winHeight)/2;
attrib = "hotkeys=true,menubar=no,personalbar=no,titlebar=yes,toolbar=no,location=no,top=" + yPos + ",left=" + xPos + ",width=" + winWidth + ",height=" + winHeight +",resizable=yes,scrollbars=no";
new_window= window.open(policyPaperUrl, policyElement, attrib);
new_window.focus();
```

}

When I right click on "DOC" link in IE8 , it does now show up "Save target As" option. I need to provide user the option to right click and Save this pdf document.

Comment: Check your function name

Comment: Apologies, provided wrong js. corrected now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can format the url like:

```
 <a href="/cpi/producer/CSPDocumentGateway?jadeAction=MCS02&<%= MCSUIKeys.ASP_MCS_DOCUMENT_SELECTED %>=<%= i %>&m=<%=aView.getCalMonth()%>&y=<%=aView.getCalYear()%>&p=<%=aView.getProducerNumber()%>' onclick="getPolicyPaper(this.href, 'pdf', '640','550'); return false;">DOC</a>
```

a better method would be to move the JS handler into an event listener.